# Python internals - How do objects know about global variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, global-variables, python-import, python-module

I recently discovered some interesting behavior that left me wondering about how an object knows about which global variables exist. For example, suppose I have a file "test.py":

```
globalVar = 1
toDelete = 2

class Test(object):
    classVar = 3

    def runTest1(self):
        print globalVar
        print toDelete
        print missingVar

    def runTest2(self):
        print self.classVar
        print toCreate
        print missingVar
```

Then in an interactive shell I do this:

```
>>> import test
>>> tester = test.Test()
>>> tester.runTest1()
1
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 10, in runTest1
    print missingVar
NameError: global name 'missingVar' is not defined
>>> tester.runTest2()
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 14, in runTest2
    print toCreate
NameError: global name 'toCreate' is not defined
```

Nothing surprising. Then I change the first few lines of "test.py" to this:

```
globalVar = 4 
toCreate = 5

class Test(object):
    classVar = 6
```

Now back to the interactive shell:

```
>>> reload(test) # test = reload(test) gives the same result 
<module 'test' from 'test.py'>
>>> tester.runTest1()
4
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 10, in runTest1
    print missingVar
NameError: global name 'missingVar' is not defined
>>> tester.runTest2()
3
5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 15, in runTest2
    print missingVar
NameError: global name 'missingVar' is not defined
>>> dir(test)
['Test', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'globalVar', 'toCreate', 'toDelete']
```

So `tester` now knows about `toCreate`, which showed up after `tester` itself was created. It still knows about `toDelete` because reloading a module apparently doesn't affect a global variable that was deleted. Here comes a twist:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import importlib
>>> del(sys.modules['test']) # remove cached version
>>> test = importlib.import_module('test') # same result if I don't have 'test = '
>>> tester.runTest1()
None
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 10, in runTest1
    print missingVar
NameError: global name 'missingVar' is not defined
>>> tester.runTest2()
3
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 15, in runTest2
    print missingVar
NameError: global name 'missingVar' is not defined
>>> dir(test)
['Test', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'globalVar', 'toCreate']
```

Deleting the module from `sys.modules` and then reimporting the module results in all the global variables becoming `None`.

Also of interest is that if I delete `test` and `sys.modules['test']`, it still knows about the values of the variables for a while. After a little while (which I assume is how long it takes for the module to be garbage collected) the values become `None`. Reimporting the module causes the garbage collection (or whatever is going on) to happen immediately.

So how does `tester` find out about a new global variable being created, and then once the module is gone why does it still know which variables existed even though it no longer knows what values they held?

Comment: Objects know nothing about scopes. *Functions* do.

Comment: @delnan Functions are objects, so... *\*ducks and runs\**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any name that is not a local (has not been assigned to in the current scope) is instead assumed to be a global. The name is looked up every time the code runs.

So at *runtime* the name is looked up in the global namespace, which is just a dictionary. If the name doesn't exist at that time, a `NameError` exception is raised.

You can see this when you disassemble a function; bytecode is shown when using the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html):

```
>>> import dis
>>> def foo():
...     bar = 'baz'  # local
...     bar  # reference the local
...     baz  # reference something else; e.g. a global
... 
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('baz')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (bar)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (bar)
              9 POP_TOP             

  4          10 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (baz)
             13 POP_TOP             
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             17 RETURN_VALUE
```

`bar` is a local (it was assigned to in the block), while `baz` is a global. The local is referenced by `LOAD_FAST`, while the global is referenced by `LOAD_GLOBAL`.

To do this, function objects have a `function.__globals__` reference linking it to the module globals mapping; see the *User-defined functions* section in the [datamodel documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

```
>>> foo.__globals__ is globals()
True
```

Python also *cleans up globals* when deleting modules; to prevent circular references holding up finalisation globals are rebound to `None` at that time (although this behaviour [changed in Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-pep-442)). If you however maintain a reference to `tester`, your code will find those `None` values.

Your `tester` instance, still referencing the original class and it's methods, are still referencing their module through their `function.__globals__` references. So, although you deleted the `sys.modules` reference to the module, triggering the module cleanup, the *globals dictionary* is still referenced by the class methods. This globals dictionary now holds `None` values for each global.

Comment: So why do I get `None` for the variables rather than a `NameError`? `toDelete` no longer exists, but `tester` still knows that it did.

Comment: @RobWatts In Python 2 when a module gets deleted all of its global variables are set to `None`. This is now fixed: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0442/

Comment: @Martijn I think it would be useful to explain *how* functions get their globals (`f.__globals__`), where that dict comes from, and what happens to a module when it's garbage collected (clearing its `__dict__`). (I don't have time right now to write a competing answer.)

Comment: I didn't know about how global variables were cleaned up. I believe that's what's going on here.

Comment: @delnan yes; I was time constrained as well (distractions elsewhere).