# TypeError when calling superclass's __init__ method

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am somehow getting a weird error when I'm trying to create an instance of a class.

```
  ...
  File <file1>, line 242, in some_method
    created_object = SubClass(obj1, obj2)
  File <file2>, line 11, in __init__
    SuperClass.__init__(self, obj1)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Here's what the two `__init__` methods look like:

```
class SubClass(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self, obj1=None, obj2=None):
        SuperClass.__init__(self, obj1)
        ...
```

and

```
class SuperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, obj1=None, obj2=None):
        self.obj1 = obj1
```

The same code in "file1" that creates the instance of the subclass also creates instances of other subclasses of the same superclass. They all receive similar objects as arguments, but only one of the subclasses is causing this error. Additionally, at least one of the working subclasses has the exact same definition and first line for its `__init__` method.

This error just recently showed up after I made some changes in "file1", but I did not touch the way in which I am instantiating the subclass objects or the objects I pass in to them.

In any case, I simply don't understand the error. What is expecting a string or buffer, and why?

Can anyone shed any light on this error?

**EDIT:**

```
self.SubClass = getattr(importlib.import_module(subclass_module), 'SubClass')
del sys.modules[subclass_module] # Premature optimization strikes again!
```

As explained in the answer I posted, I figured out that the above is what is causing this error to occur. However, a little digging has left me even more confused about the error itself. I changed the `__init__` method to this:

```
def __init__(self, obj1=None, obj2=None):
    print None.__init__
    None.__init__('Hello', 'World')
```

and called it like this:

```
print None.__init__
None.__init__('Hello', 'World')
obj = self.SubClass(obj1, obj2)
```

and I'm *still* getting the `TypeError` in the `__init__` method, *but not when I call it right before that*. Here are the two lines disassembled using the [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html)

```
# None.__init__('Hello', 'World') in SubClass.__init__
10       9 LOAD_CONST                0 (None)
         12 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__init__)
         15 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello')
         18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('World')
         21 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         24 POP_TOP

# None.__init__('Hello', 'World') right before I try to create the SubClass object
246      147 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         150 LOAD_ATTR                7 (__init__)
         153 LOAD_CONST               5 ('Hello')
         156 LOAD_CONST               6 ('World')
         159 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         162 POP_TOP
```

The output of the two prints that I put in is this:

```
<method-wrapper '__init__' of NoneType object at 0x102977538>
<method-wrapper '__init__' of NoneType object at 0x102977538>
```

So it's the same `__init__` method each time called with constants, but with different results. What is going on here?

Comment: `super(SubClass, self).__init__(obj1, *args, **kwargs)` ?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that does so.

Comment: @martineau I can't create a SSCCE that reproduces the error. I figured out the source of the problem, but the error itself is still an absolute enigma to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to `super(SubClass, self).__init__(obj)` didn't fix the problem but did change the error to this:

```
TypeError: must be type, not None
```

[Based on something I learned previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020108/python-internals-how-do-objects-know-about-global-variables) the change that caused this issue was some (probably premature) memory optimization I was trying to do - deleting the module from `sys.modules`. Along came the garbage collection, and both `SubClass` and the import of `SuperClass` became `None`. Leaving the module in `sys.modules` eliminates the problem.

Knowing the cause of the error doesn't help me understand the error itself though. I still don't understand why I am getting `TypeError: expected string or buffer`.